# YouTube annotations not working on Firefox 33.0 (Kubuntu 14.10)

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, flash, html5

After updating my Kubuntu to 14.10, I can not see the video annotations on YouTube videos. I tried to turn off Flash Player, but the annotations does not work neither in the HTML5 player.

Any ideas?

(Sorry for my English.)

**Edit:** Possible solution is to use Chromium instead of Firefox. Does anyone please know, how to fix this issue in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded Firefox to 34.0 and annotations began to work, so it might be a bug in the previous version (33.0).

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution: Annotations are working properly in Chromium:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

#### More info about the problem:

Today I noticed I have this same problem. The annotations on my videos and on other user's videos were visible, now they are all gone. I want to add a few details that might help:

- When I edit the annotations on my videos they are correctly shown in the annotations editor, but not when watching the video normally.
- I use adblock plus, but disabling it completely does not help.
- The new annotation ads that youtube includes in the bottom left corner of some videos are visible (the ones that slide).
- The channel icon people can add in their videos in a corner is visible.
- Ads in general are visible.
- When I right click in a video it shows me, among other things, "About Adobe Flash Player [version here]". So I am pretty sure it is not the html5 player.

*As stated above, the annotations are working properly on Chromium.*

Comment: Thanks for specifying the problem, the symptoms are similar. :) I would like to continue using Firefox, so using Chromium is not a solution for me. :|